# Why does freeing a pointer cause program to abort?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have been working with function pointers and structs for a personal project. When I compiled and ran my code I got an "aborted (core dumped)" error when I tried to free a pointer.

I have the following code (excluding imports):

```
typedef int (*intFunction)(int,int);  

typedef struct {
    int value;
    intFunction func;
} ValueFunc;

int addInts(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    ValueFunc vf;
    vf.value = 3;
    vf.func = &addInts;
    int y = vf.func(vf.value,4);
    printf("%i",y);
    free(vf.func);
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could explain why this is happening I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: You are trying to free something that has not been dynamically allocated.

Comment: Did you try compiling with full warnings? And the conversion from function-pointer to `void*` passed unremarked? See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a9598c6388c6b3a

Comment: Why would you want to free that poor function pointer?

Comment: I now realize what I have done wrong. I had assumed wrongly that because it was a pointer I should free it after I was done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SterlingTolley Not every pointer needs freeing, only the ones that you allocate dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to `free` what you dynamically allocated (for example by using `calloc`, `malloc` or any function from that family).

You never allocated memory, so you do not need to free it. And passing a random pointer to the `free` function will make it misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/504956-do-you-have-delete-function-pointer where a user says:

> You should not delete function pointers. The function is located
>   somewhere inside your executable. When you execute your program, the
>   OS will load the executable into memory. When your program assigns a
>   value to the function pointer, it will get the value that points to
>   the location of the function in your executable. If you delete it in
>   your program, your compiler will most likely complain about you're
>   trying to delete a object that is not a pointer.

... so even if your compiler don't give any errors it will most likely fail during execution